# Differences in conductivity as temp rises for intrinsic vs extrinsic semiconductrs

Tags: electricity, temperature, semiconductor-physics

For a doped semiconductor, near the end of the extrinsic temp region due to heightened effects of lattice scattering conductivity goes down "temporarily" (temperature wise).

[image: doped semiconductor]

What happens to the conductivity of an intrinsic semiconductor in that same region? Does it follow a similar plot or are there differences?

Until now I thought that for an intrinsic semiconductor, conductivity will always rise as temperature rises, due to rise in charge density having greater effect than reduction of mobility (in the case of an intrinsic semiconductor).